# Is there a way I can re use view template files in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am very new to angualrjs and ionic, so for my application i have a set of html code which is reused in multiple view templates. Is there a way I can move those repeated code to a file and include in the templates as I wanted.

Eg - I have a three different types of product details pages each have a block which shows the product price details. So If I can move the price part to another template file I can maintain/modify those part easily.

Comment: You might be able to convert the "product price details" to a directive, and then reuse that wherever you need to within your application.

Comment: I dint quite understand what you said. Could you point me to some blog or articles ?

Comment: No problem, these links are helpful in understanding directives: https://goo.gl/pUwVAw (Angular docs) & http://goo.gl/f4T1GN (SitePoint).

Comment: this what I exactly wanted Thanks.